# OpenMP Declare Reduction clause not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a function to count primes in parallel using open mp's parallel for syntax and I am trying to use a custom reduction function that merges in order two vectors:

```
    void mergeVecs(std::vector<int>& inVec1, std::vector<int>& inVec2) {
        std::vector<int> outVec;
        outVec.reserve(inVec1.size() + inVec2.size());
        std::ranges::merge(inVec1, inVec2, std::back_inserter(outVec));
        inVec1 = outVec;
    }

#pragma omp declare reduction(mergeVecs: std::vector<int>: \
mergeVecs(omp_out, omp_in) initializer (omp_priv=omp_orig)

    std::vector<int> ompCountPrimes(int initial, int limit, int increment) {
        std::vector<int> primes{ };
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(mergeVecs: primes)
        for (int i = initial; i < limit; i += increment) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                primes.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        return primes;
    }
```

It was modeled after the advice in the accepted answer of this post: [custom omp reduction on std::map's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034114/custom-omp-reduction-on-stdmaps)

However, attempting to build in the latest version of visual studio I get the following errors: **'mergeVecs': invalid operator token in OpenMP 'reduction' clause**, and **'declare': expected an OpenMP directive name**. It seems like the compiler isn't even recognizing the omp delcare reduction statement although I'm pretty sure I'm following te correct syntax (https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu117.html#x152-1790002.21.5.7). Could this be an issue with the MSVC compiler? I also tried compiling with the `/openmp:llvm` and `/openmp:experimental` flags with the same result. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: The MSVC OpenMP runtime is completely obsolete since more than 20 years old. I advise people not to use it. More recently they finally decided to use the LLVM runtime but the support is still AFAIK not complete. Advanced features are often not fully implemented yet. This is an advanced feature so it seems normal to me. If you can, please consider using LLVM for this.

Comment: That being said, I think this reduction is not efficient anyway : it makes a lot of temporary vectors that will make things memory bound. A critical section might be more efficient for the final appending. Alternatively, each thread can store a pointer to their local vector in a shared array and the master thread can merge all of them (this should be actually already done by your code though your code also perform many additional merges before).

Comment: Please consider using `inVec1 = std::move(outVec);` to avoid a useless expensive additional copy. Note that `std::ranges::merge` is probably not useful either since the two array are sorted and the last item of the first array should be smaller than the first item of the second one based on your loop, assuming the scheduling is `static` (it is `auto` by default which AFAIK is often similar to `static` in practice). If you want ot use a dynamic scheduler, then you can sort blocks rather than each item separately (more efficient).

Comment: 1. Complicated reductions in OMP/C++ are very compiler dependent. You may need to try more than one compiler, and not the one in Visual Studio. 2. The "declare reduction" is not the most elegant solution: better to define `operator+` on maps. You may need to write a minimal class around `std::map`. 3. I don't share @JérômeRichard 's concern about bandwidth since there are far fewer primes than ints.